# How to fix a "Deceptive-site-ahead" Chrome warning in my PHP website?

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, security, warnings

The following PHP code is working as it should be but showing a warning in Chrome that "Deceptive-site-ahead" as shown in the screenshot below.

What changes are required to resolve the problem?

I am hashing the password before inserting into the database.

[image]

```
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","", "onlineexam");
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error ;
}
  $_SESSION['message'] = "<span class='alert alert-success'>Database Connection Successful.</span>";


//the form has been submitted with post
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
  {

    //two passwords are equal to each other
    if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['conf_password']) 
    {

        //set all the post variables
        $username = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $user_role = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['user_role']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //md5 has password for security

      //Duplicate check username is primary key
                $dupesql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username'");
                  $row_cnt = $dupesql->num_rows;
                  if( $row_cnt > 0)
                  {
                      $_SESSION['message']  = "Username is already exist.";

                  }
                else
                {
                    //insert user data into database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,password,user_role) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password','$user_role')";


                    if ($conn->query($sql) == true)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "<span class='alert alert-success' style='.body-content{display:none;}'>Registration successful! 
                                                  </span><br/><br/>
                                                  <a href='login.php'>
                                                     <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' > Login </button>
                                                  </a>";
                    }
                    else {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = 'User could not be added to the database!';
                         }
                } 
    }
    else 
       {
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Password does not match the confirm password.';
       }
   }
```

Comment: The security warning is based on something your page is doing that makes Chrome think your page is trying to exploit users. Nothing you posted here gives any indication as to what that is. use `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to display your page source in plaintext in another browser, and post that, then you can be helped.

Comment: check this site out: https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-remove-google-blacklist-warning

Comment: Aside: since you're using MySQLi, you should be using parameter binding, not parameter escaping. The latter contains some edge-cases in which SQL injection is still possible, and so parameter binding should be preferred where possible.